# $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change" not working on second time

Tags: jquery-mobile

On click of a button , i am reloading the same page this way

```
(document).on('click', '.cancelyes', function(event) {
alert('herree');
var uuid = '123';
var screen_id = '910';
var cust_id = '122';
var minimum_order = 133;
var addreslabel = '222'
$(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "index.html?UUID=" + uuid + '&screen_id=' + screen_id + '&cust_id=' + cust_id + '&minimum_order=' + minimum_order + '&addreslabel=' + addreslabel+ '&accessedfrom=' + accessedfrom  );
});
```

This works fine for the first time , but if i re do the operation , why doesn't its loading the same page again ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pagecontainer documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) on options:

> **allowSamePageTransition** (default: false)
>   By default, change() ignores requests to change to the current active page. Setting this option to true allows the request to execute.

Comment: Thank you , as mentioned i have used allowSamePageTransition:true but still i see the issue .

Comment: Thank you very much , it got solved using allowSamePageTransition:true,reload:true

Comment: Thanks again , i was struggling this for 5 hours